# I want to get the final version of the program but I encountered this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get the final version of the program but I encountered this error

Could not find lint-gradle.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.2.1/lint-gradle-26.2.1.jar

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (such books/tutorials, tools/libraries) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    // The order in which you list these repositories matter.
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
}
```

to your top level `build.gradle`

it seems that you forgot to add `google()`